# Any articles on how to get started building your own browser?

Tags: browser, webkit, gecko

Hello recently I've been a bit curious and wanted to make a browser. I'd like to use an existing engine though such as Gecko or Webkit. Are there any resources on the web for how to get started and any examples? Language choice doesn't really matter(but no VB please. That was the only example code I found)

Answer (score 5):

> **[Chromium](http://www.chromium.org/Home)** is an open-source browser project that aims to build a safer, faster, and more stable way for all Internet users to experience the web. This site contains design documents, architecture overviews, testing information, and more to help you learn to build and work with the Chromium source code.

Or study some [applications using Webkit](http://trac.webkit.org/wiki/Applications%20using%20WebKit) for example. Chances are, these projects are not as complex as chromium.

Comment: I'm not really looking to study a huge project or to try to modify an existing browser. I'd like to see basically what it takes to get started for using one of the above Layout engines

Answer (score 1):

I'd recommend you build a browser in Java with Swing or SWT. They have all the components you'll need, so you need to put them together and start figuring out the tougher problems. The documentation is good, and you may even find tutorials that get you most of the way there.

I recently downloaded the code for Firefox or Chrome, and this seems like a much more difficult place to start. There's lots of setup and overhead to get a build working on your machine compared with a Java app.

Comment: But I can already compile firefox with two commands. I use OpenBSD and Linux so Java is actually more difficult for me to use(compared to Windows)